# Assertion error when reading an excel file from the URL using Pandas

Tags: python, excel, pandas, error-handling

I am trying to read an excel directly from a URL using:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel('https://apps.fomento.gob.es/BoletinOnline2/sedal/34010110.XLS')
```

However i get this error:

```
File "<ipython-input-153-d6607f341e37>", line 3, in <module>
    df = pd.read_excel('https://apps.fomento.gob.es/BoletinOnline2/sedal/34010110.XLS')

  File "D:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\util\_decorators.py", line 299, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)

  File "D:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel\_base.py", line 336, in read_excel
    io = ExcelFile(io, storage_options=storage_options, engine=engine)

  File "D:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel\_base.py", line 1131, in __init__
    self._reader = self._engines[engine](self._io, storage_options=storage_options)

  File "D:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel\_xlrd.py", line 25, in __init__
    super().__init__(filepath_or_buffer, storage_options=storage_options)

  File "D:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel\_base.py", line 391, in __init__
    self.book = self.load_workbook(self.handles.handle)

  File "D:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel\_xlrd.py", line 38, in load_workbook
    return open_workbook(file_contents=data)

  File "D:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\xlrd\__init__.py", line 172, in open_workbook
    bk = open_workbook_xls(

  File "D:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\xlrd\book.py", line 104, in open_workbook_xls
    bk.parse_globals()

  File "D:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\xlrd\book.py", line 1213, in parse_globals
    self.handle_sst(data)

  File "D:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\xlrd\book.py", line 1180, in handle_sst
    self._sharedstrings, rt_runlist = unpack_SST_table(strlist, uniquestrings)

  File "D:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\xlrd\book.py", line 1476, in unpack_SST_table
    assert _unused_i == nstrings - 1

AssertionError
```

I have also tried to read the excel of that URL by writing the content to an excel file and then reading it, but i get the same error:

```
import requests 
import pandas as pd

req = requests.get('https://apps.fomento.gob.es/BoletinOnline2/sedal/34010110.XLS' )
url_content = req.content
open('my_file.xls', 'wb').write(url_content)
df = pd.read_excel('my_file.xls')
```

After I open 'my_file.xls' with Office and save it from there, I can read it with Pandas as usual with 'df= pd.read_excel('my_file.xls')', but this happens with a lot of excels that I am trying to read so i can't go one by one saving them manually.

I don't know what could be happening. Thank you for your help.